# Image not displaying in view. from database

Tags: php, laravel-5

In my laravel project I tried to load images from database. But it displays the broken link. But when I inspect the image it shows the link. But when i clicked the link it shows 404 error.....
this is my codes

this is the code of view
.............

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
    <a href="{{ route('posts.create') }}" class="btn btn-success mb-2">Add Posts</a>
</div>

<div class="card card-default">
    <div class="card-header">Posts</div>

    <div class="card-body">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <th>Image</th>
                <th>Title</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach ($posts as $post)
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src="{{ asset($post->image) }}"></td>
                        <td>{{ $post->title }}</td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

.............

and this is the code of controller

```
public function store(CreatePostsRequest $request)
{
    //Upload the image

    $image = $request->image->store('public/img');
    //create the post
    Post::create([
        'title' => $request->title,
        'description' => $request->description,
        'content' => $request->content,
        'image' => $image
    ]);
    //flash a message with seasson

    session()->flash('success','Post created successfully');
    //redirect user

    return redirect(route('posts.index'));


}
```

and i linked the storage to the public folder. But still its not working

Comment: Have you done a `dd()` https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-dd and or printed  `asset($post->image` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php yet? What were the results? What was the path on screen and what was it in reality? Update your question with more feedback.

Comment: yes i did that the url was <img src="http://echoaid.test:8080/storage/app/public/posts/al770M4eXLpxn84JB1gSqSiRk6096p2bj5BSOlCU.jpeg">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give the absolute path and not use {{ asset... }}. Try something like this:

```
<img src="/xx/storage/app/public/FinalFolder/{{$post->image}}">
```

Comment: like this:
<img src="ECHOAID:8080/storage/app/public/posts/{{$post->image}}">

Comment: The path of the image should be right is all that is required.

Comment: @Sajid285
This will not work in live but will do on the local server.
You need to see how images are being stored in the folder when they are uploaded.

Comment: <img src="/storage/app/public/posts/{{$post->image}}"> try this...
You don't need the project name. Upvote if it works.